# Consecutive LOOP through different fields from different not linked tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, select, plpgsql

I have a couple of tables presenting different entities on the site. Links between them does not matter for my task. (And this is not my design, also). 
I want to go through some of text fields to do hard work like translations, spell checking etc. There are **a lot** of text.

My question is: can I have a query for a FOR LOOP through all those tables sequentially. Is array_cat as in example below an adequate decision, or it will eat all my ram? There is another variant - to make a second function that receives a table name as parameter. I'll be happy to select a simpler decision.

This test example below don't work with syntax error in array_cat. The operator || gives me the syntax error also.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  qs TEXT;
BEGIN
  FOR qs IN array_cat( -- as @ammoQ suggested to do UNION ALL
    SELECT array_agg(messages) FROM posts UNION ALL
    SELECT array_agg(comments) FROM boards )
  LOOP
    -- here I need: count chars really processed
    -- to do not exceed the billing quota of external api
    -- then make an UPSERT into cache table for another long process
    -- if quota is not exceeded
  END LOOP;
-- and return total of processed symbols
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I dont see why you would aggregate text to array and concatenate all in one later to do work on text... why not do same **lot of work** on each text column in each row separately?.. And not in loop, but in `SELECT`?..

Comment: I just don't know the proper sql-way to it. After have some optimizations I need to just do an UPSERT inside the loop. I edited this example.

Comment: please provide table and data samples and text precess example. I think plpgsql processing here would be too expensive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `union`

EDIT: removed `array_agg`

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  qs TEXT;
BEGIN
  FOR qs IN (
    SELECT messages x FROM posts union all
    SELECT comments FROM boards )
  LOOP
    RAISE DEBUG 'TEXT is %', qs.x;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Looks like UNION ALL makes me happy :)
And without array_agg this works as I want.
But I need more. As I know recursive CTE can do the job of break the loop if chars quota will exceed. Use case - we bought the translation API  to process a 128000000 symbols. So I have to stop processing when this limit will be reached. Which one is better in such case: rCTE or FOR LOOP?